# Drawing pentagon,hexagon in Pygame

Tags: python, algorithm, pygame, python-3.4

I'm trying to make functions that can draw pentagon hexagon etc. Troubling on algorithm, should I compare the lines with `pygame.draw.line` ? It looks like too much work around the determine coords of lines. Is there an easy way to draw them? Also I don't know another library that can draw these things. I know only Pygame, Is there another one ?

Comment: It's just a sudden inspiration as I'm still at work here, but did you try to draw everything from the centre of the figure? I'm thinking of a function which receives the distance of the points from the centre and then calculates their positions using angles. I'll think it through when I'm home, but maybe it gives you new ideas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can draw it using `lines`. You only need to generate list of vertices with simple trigonometry.

Something like this (if I didn't make a mistake):

```
def draw_ngon(Surface, color, n, radius, position):
    pi2 = 2 * 3.14

    for i in range(0, n):
        pygame.draw.line(Surface, color, position, (cos(i / n * pi2) * radius + position[0], sin(i / n * pi2) * radius + position[1]))

    return pygame.draw.lines(Surface,
          color,
          True,
          [(cos(i / n * pi2) * radius + position[0], sin(i / n * pi2) * radius + position[1]) for i in range(0, n)])
```

Comment: @GLHF I think so, also I've just added addinational parameter for position.

Comment: `from math import *` or `math.cos` `math.sin`

Comment: It's working but I want to show the lines inside the pentagon,hexagon too. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @GLHF Lines from center to vertices?

Comment: It's a brilliant job. Wish I can up your answer twice, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pygame.draw.polygon(surface, color, point_list, width=0)` to draw a polygon. In this case, you can use trigonometry to generate a list of vertices and pass it as the `point_list` parameter. Here is a function that draws any regular polygon having `vertex_count` vertices:

```
def draw_regular_polygon(surface, color, vertex_count, radius, position, width=0):
    n, r = vertex_count, radius
    x, y = position
    pygame.draw.polygon(surface, color, [
        (x + r * cos(2 * pi * i / n), y + r * sin(2 * pi * i / n))
        for i in range(n)
    ], width)
```

You can run [this demo](https://replit.com/@ArthurKhazbs/DrawRegularPolygon) and see this function in action, changing the vertex count with UP / DOWN arrow keys.

Comment: Is there a way so that it is not filled? i.e. just the sides, not the inside.

Comment: @CELLSecret If you want to draw a polygon outline you need to specify the `width` parameter when calling `pygame.draw.polygon`. This optional 4th parameter controls the width of the outline drawn. By default it equals to `0`, which means the polygon should be filled instead. Thank you for your comment, I added this parameter to the function signature in my answer.

Comment: I also updated [the demo](https://replit.com/@ArthurKhazbs/DrawRegularPolygon) and moved it over to replIt, now you can run it in your browser with one click of a button